# grouping table based on upper and lower limit in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables & using SQL Server 2012

**tblBondFund**

```
Name     Maturity    Wgt
ABC      2.4         8
NBV      6           7
LPM      9           2
KOP      4           5.5
```

**tblLimits**

```
LowerLimit    UpperLimit
1             5
6             8
8             10
```

Before I explain what I am after it might be easier if I show the final result I require,

```
Limit   wgt
1 - 5   13.5
6 - 8   7
9 - 10  2
```

So in my tblBondFund I want to group all bonds which maturities fall within a certain range - the ranges are in my tblLimits.

Currently how I achieve my result it to query my tblBondFund with a where clause like below,

```
 where Maturity >= 1 and Maturity < 5
```

I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this? Normally there would be more groups than 3 but was just showing an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `left join`:

```
select replace(replace('@l - @u', '@l', l.lowerlimit), '@u', l.upperlimit) as limit,
       sum(bf.wgt) as wgt
from tblLimits l left join
     tblBondFund bf
     on bf.maturity >= l.lowerlimit and bf.maturity <= l.upperlimit
group by l.lowerlimit, l.upperlimit
order by l.lowerlimit;
```

When you realize that your logic removes values between 5 and 6, you'll want to either change the limits table or adjust the logic in the `on` clause.